# Why is my if statement only returning the second result?

Tags: vb.net

My calculations work but every time I run the program my output will be the "negative, does not exceed" result. I'm very new to all this so please any suggestions will help.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim foodname As String = MaskedTextBox1.Text
        Dim calories As Integer = MaskedTextBox2.Text
        Dim fat As Integer = MaskedTextBox3.Text
        Dim calculation As Double = (fat * 9) / calories
        Dim positive As String = "which exceeds AHA recommendation"
        Dim negative As String = "which does not exceed AHA recommendation"
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()

        If ((fat * 9) / calories) > (0.3 * 100) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(foodname & " contains " & FormatPercent(calculation) & " calories from fat, " & positive)
        ElseIf ((fat * 9) / calories) < (0.29 * 100) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(foodname & " contains " & FormatPercent(calculation) & " calories from fat, " & negative)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would this help?

```
    If ((fat * 9) / calories) > (0.3 * 100) Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(foodname & " contains " & FormatPercent(calculation) & " calories from fat, " & positive)
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Add(foodname & " contains " & FormatPercent(calculation) & " calories from fat, " & negative)
    End If
```

you have only two options here, no need for 2 conditions. either the first one is true, or it must be the second one

Comment: In addition to being redundant, with the original code, neither branch will be executed if `(fat * 9) / calories)` evaluates to something beween 29 and 30 inclusive.